# Is it possible to load Files in tests on remote CI/CD server? [BitBucket Pipeline]

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, filepath

I'm trying to run a test for resizing images. To do that I have an Image that I load into a `File`.
This works locally (in IDE and via terminal) but fails in BitBucket's pipeline.

File structure:

[image]

Code that loads the image:

```
    String rootDir = Directory.current.path;
    imagePath = rootDir + '/test/assets/test_image_gradient_black_white_3000x4000.png';
    File myFile = File(filePath);
```

This works locally, but when run in Bitbucket's pipeline the "current path" returned "does not exist".

Error message:

```
00:03 +24 -4: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/my_repository/test/image_utils_test/image_utils_test.dart: given 3000x4000 pixel file - resize with half width - verify resize and aspect ratio kept [E]
  FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/test/assets/test_image_gradient_black_white_3000x4000.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Is it possible to load files in CI?

Answer (score 0):

The path was actually wrong.
When you right click a test in android studio and select run it is run from that path.
When you run it from the terminal you have to supply the full path of your file from where you are currently standing.

`Directory.current.path` always returns the project root path, and since my test was in a separate module I had to add the path manually.
This should **only** be done if we are not already in the `my_repository` module, otherwise we will add the path twice and we would not be able to run the tests from the IDE instead.

This is how I calculate what to add to the string depending on where the test was executed.

```
  String get testRootDir {
    String rootDir = Directory.current.path;
    String testDir =
        rootDir.contains('/my_repository') 
          ? rootDir + '/test' 
          : rootDir + '/my_repository/test';
    return testDir;
  }
  ...
  ...
  final String assetPath = testRootDir + 'assets/test_image_gradient_black_white_3000x4000.png';
```